# Ошибка ': not a valid identifiere при выполнении простого bash-скрипта

Tags: bash

Код скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -rp "Ab number:   " Number
printf "Number: %s\\n" "$Number"
read -rp "Ab name   " Name
printf "Name:: %s\\n" "$Name"
```

Запуск:

```
$ bash an.sh
Ab number:   78544
': not a valid identifierber
Number:
Ab name   Test
': not a valid identifiere
Name::
```

Лишних управляющих символов нет, проверила в vi.

С чем связана эта ошибка и как исправить?

И как читать пользовательский ввод, но обойтись без printf, если значение переменной потом не нужно выводить на экран?
Спасибо.

Comment: Xто подразумеваете под "Читать пользовательский ввод"? И чисто личный интерес - что такое "vi"&

Comment: read ожидает от пользователя данные и записывает их в переменную Number. vi - текстовый редактор.

Comment: именно такие сообщения и получаете: то «identifierber», то «identifiere» вместо «identifier»?

Comment: Уберите двойной слэш в выводе. Точнее замените его одинарным.

Answer (score 1):

Все-таки проблема была в символах перевода строк CRLF
Заменила все на LF, заработало